# background process catching process id before termination

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am trying to emulate background and foreground process in C. While doing that if there is a '&' symbol in end, I am avoiding waiting for that child process in parent process. I am also storing all background commands I execute in a list and try to remove them from the list when they are done. But in case of ls -l& the output is shown immediately and by just pressing enter the process terminates. How to catch that process id and remove from my list if it matches with the existing pids in the list.

```
pid = fork();
//Code to add pid into a list if it is a background process
//this is done by parent as pid is always 0 for child processes
if(pid == 0){
    if(proc_state=='&'){
        setsid();           
    }
        // logic for creating command
        int ret= execvp( subcomm[0], subcomm );
    // handling error
}

//Parent will execute this
//Child will never come here if execvp executed successfully

if(proc_sate != '&'){
        for(i=0; i < count_pipe+1; i++){            
            int ret = waitpid(0, &flag ,0);
        // Code to remove procid from list if 'ret' matches with existing procid in the list.
        }
}

//Here proc_state just determines whether it is background or foreground.It is just a character. count_pipe is just a 
//variable holding number of pipes
```

Hope I am clear. Please ask questions if any doubt

Comment: I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: What's wrong with `ls -l&` showing its output immediately? That's what would happen in most shells.  What is that `pipe_count` exactly and why is it relevant to the number of times you `waitpid()`?

Comment: There's no virtue in capturing the return value from `execvp()` because it is always -1.  If the function returns, it failed.  If it succeeds, it does not return.  The cause of failure is in `errno`.  Note too that the comment `//Child will never come here` should be true regardless of whether `execvp()` was successful or not; the child should never get back into the code for the parent process.  The `// handling error` code should always `exit()` or `_exit()` and not return.  (All categorical statements should be treated with a small pinch of salt, but are accurate 99.x% of the time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd use [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) in a loop like:

```
int status;
pid_t corpse;

while ((corpse = waitpid(0, &status, WNOHANG)) != -1)
{
    /* Process PID of child that died with given status */
    ...
}
```

This gathers up any children that have died, but returns when there are no more corpses to collect.  The option 0 means 'any dead children in my process group'; an alternative option -1 means 'any dead children at all'.  In other circumstances, you might specify a specific PID to see if that child has died, or a negative number would specify any child in the process group with the PGID equal to the absolute value.

The WNOHANG means 'do not hang waiting for a child to die if there are no bodies currently dead'; using 0 means 'wait around until a child of the appropriate category does die', though the call will return when there are no such children left.

If there are multiple children in the process group, there's no guarantee about the order in which the corpses will be returned, just as there's no guarantee about the order in which the children will die.

It isn't entirely clear what your requirements are.  You might choose the last argument to `waitpid()` based on whether the last pipeline launched was run in the background, for example.  If you previously launched a process in the background, you might collect its corpse at almost any time (unless you're waiting for a different process group, or a specific PID other than that background PID).  You might well choose the first argument to `waitpid()` differently depending on the circumstances.