# How to send SIGINT to background processes only in C

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am writing a simple shell program, where I can execute some background processes. I want using a specific command like "killbg" be able to SIGINT every background processes I have executed. I have tried:

1. Make a process group consisting of only background processes using `setpgid(0,0)`
   in the clause where `pid=fork()` is 0, i.e. when I'm going to execute the child process.
2. The process group 'pgid' I get after the `setpgid(0,0)` statement, I use in kill function, like `kill(pgid, 2)`.

Unfortunately, the whole program gets interrupted, and background tasks are still running.

Here is the relevant code:

```
while(1){
  fgets.. //user input for command

  // Kill background processes      
        if(strcmp(execArgs[0], "killbg") == 0){    //execArgs argument array for execve
            kill(pgid, 2); 
            perror("");
        }
        pid=fork();

        // Error in fork
        if(pid <= -1){
            perror("Error with fork.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }       
        // Child process
        else if(pid == 0){
            if(execBG == TRUE){    // execBG true If user wants to run command in background
                setpgid(0,0);
                pgid = getpgid(pid);
            }
            execve(execArgs[0], execArgs, NULL); 
            fprintf(stderr, "Not a valid command! Remember the full path.\n");  

        }
        // Parent process       
        else{
            if(execBG==FALSE){
                waitpid(-1, &status, NULL);
            }
            else{
                ;    // if background process, don't wait for the child
            }
        }               
    }  
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You set `pgid` in the child and excute `kill()` on `pgid`in the parent, which does not know what the child set for `pgid`.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing...
1) Did you make sure that your main process is part of a different group?
2) Your parent probably receives a SIGPIPE as soon as your child(s) die because of stdin/stdout/stderr connections. Default signal action of SIGPIPE is to terminate (see signal(7)).

Comment: No you didn't understand. The parent gets interrupted with my kill function. And did I make sure if its different group? Thats exactly part of my question. I believe not and ask how to do it.

Comment: @ot0: If one wants to make sure to not be taken as rude, one might word "*I seem to not have expressed myself well enought*" instead of "*you did not understand*".

Answer (score 0):

Look at the specification of the POSIX [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) function to see how to send signals to a process group:

> If *pid* is greater than 0, *sig* shall be sent to the process whose process ID is equal to *pid*.
>
> If *pid* is 0, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.
>
> If *pid* is -1, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) for which the process has permission to send that signal.
>
> If *pid* is negative, but not -1, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of *pid*, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.

So, to send `SIGINT` to a process group, you need to call `kill(-pgrp, SIGINT)`.  You should also, always, check the return value from a system call, so you know when it fails.

I observe that you print an error message if `execve()` fails (aka returns) — that's good!  It is usually correct to exit the program at that point too.  Otherwise, you tend to have an extra process trying to read your terminal input, which is apt to be messy and confusing.

Note that `kill(pgrp, 2); perror("");` is bad because `errno` can be set to a non-zero value before `kill()` is called, or by `kill()` even if it does not report failure.  You must test the return value from system calls to know whether `errno` is relevant, and you should only call `perror()` if it is relevant.  (That presumes you should ever call `perror()`; IMO, it is a pretty lame excuse for an error reporting function, but it is better than nothing when used correctly.)

Your `waitpid()` call is not not safe.  The third argument is an integer, not a pointer.  Also, you could have multiple child processes running in the background; that code only waits for one to exit — any child process.  You almost certainly need a loop there, and probably need WNOHANG too.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm trying to understand all of these concepts among others reading your answer on another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804486/background-process-catching-process-id-before-termination). I think that before the kill function i need to understand the concept of separating child and parent processes into different groups.